# using cin.get() doubles output in code

Tags: c++

So I am teaching myself C++ and I cant see what is wrong here:

**code:**

```
// Arrays.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char input = ' ';

    for(i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "enter a value for element number " << i << ": " ;
        do
        {
            input = std::cin.get();
            std::cout << "recorded element in position " << i << " is " << input << "\n"; 
        } while (!input == 'q') ;
    }
}
```

**problem:**

line 17: input `std::cin.get();`

It gives me this: It asks for input, then records it and automatically completes element 2 for me

> enter a value for element number 1: `5 recorded element in position 1`
>   is 5 enter a value for element number 2: `recorded element in position`
>   2 is
>   enter a value for element number 3:

But when I replace it with `std::cin >> input` it doesn't, why?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you *entered* a newline: when you use the return key, you'll get another character (`'\n'`) which is also obtained from `std::cin.get()`. The member `std::istream::get()` is an unformatted input function which doesn't attempt to skip whitespace before trying to read whatever if tries to read.

On the other hand, when using formatted input, e.g., `std::cin >> input` the stream will skip all leading whitespace before trying to read something. That is, the newline you also entered is skipped.

You can use `(std::cin >> std::ws).get()` to have leading whitespace consumed before using `get()`. ... and the other way around, you can set up the stream not skip leading whitespace automatically for formatted input using `std::cin >> std::noskipws` (and reverse this setting again using `std::cin >> std::skipws`). In general it isn't advisable to not skip leading whitespace for formatted input, though.